# fgets() function can't accept message from command prompt

Tags: c, centos, fgets

I’m trying to make a C program which is prompting the user to type a message from the console and then show that message the user has typed, as in the  following example:

```
C:>promptTest
type your message >>>>  test
typed :  test

C:>
```

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(){
    char msg[32];
    printf("type your message >>>>\t");
    fgets(msg,sizeof(msg),stdin);
    msg[strlen(msg) - 1] = '\0';
    printf("typed :  %s\n",msg);
    return 0;
}
```

It can be built on both Windows7 and CentOS and it can be run normally on Windows like above.

However, it can’t be run on CentOS. I mean nothing accepts any message from the prompt like below:

```
$ ./promptTest
type your message >>>>  test

typed :  
$
```

How can I fix this?

Here is information about my machine.

```
$ cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS release 6.4 (Final)
$ 
$ arch
x86_64
$
```

Comment: working for me in CentOS. Are you using same source in both? means in first output in windows like `### buf =` and your try in centOS output different like `### buf(1) =`

Comment: The example text  was wrong and I edited it .

Comment: Your code still does not correspond to the example output.

Comment: my code is same.Output example text on windows was wrong.

Comment: No the code still doesn't match the output. Under "This is my code." you write `buf =` to the output, your output says `buf(n) = ` in all cases. This has nothing to do with the bug but it shows that this is not the code you actually compile and run. So there might be errors in some part of the code which we do not see.

Comment: Now I renewed the every examples and source codo in my question.

Comment: `strlen()` returns `size_t`, but `printf` with a `%d` expects `int`.

Comment: Isn't `buf[strlen(buf) - 1] = '\0';` redundant, seeing that `buf[strlen(buf) - 1]` contains `\0` already?

Comment: @opd no, that'd be `buf[strlen(buf)]`. I guess OP wants to remove the `'\n'`.

Comment: I simplifeid all of example in my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

CL+LF coused this matter.

see [Controlling prompt for command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22248781/controlling-prompt-for-command-line)

Answer (score 0):

`strlen()` returns `size_t` not `int`.

Printing `size_t` on a 64bit IXish system using `%d` might fail, as the former most likly is 64bit while the latter expects 32bit.

So at least on a 64bit IXish system instead of

```
printf("### buf(%d) = %s\n",strlen(buf),buf);
printf("### message(%d) = %s\n",strlen(message),message);
```

do

```
printf("### buf(%zu) = %s\n",strlen(buf),buf);
printf("### message(%zu) = %s\n",strlen(message),message);
```

As a (ugly) workaround you could also cast `strlen()` down to `int`.

```
printf("### buf(%d) = %s\n", (int) strlen(buf),buf);
printf("### message(%d) = %s\n", (int) strlen(message),message);
```

This workaround however assumes no string being longer then `INT_MAX`.

Comment: Sorry,I tied your code but it doesn't work.No accepting message.

Comment: Compile using symbols (option `-g`) for gcc and then run the code using a debugger (gdb) to see what **really** happens.

Comment: You might like to enable all warnings by adding theoptions `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`.

Comment: It shows `unused parameter ‘agrc’`,`unused parameter ‘argv’` and `Control may reach end of non- void function`

Comment: I tired to remove those warnings.And I edited the code in my question.Now there isn't any warnings.